# A new session could not be created. (Original error: Instruments crashed on startup)

Tags: xcode-instruments, appium, nativeapplication

Facing this issue while working on appium. couldnt able to launch the app in the simulator as appium server is throwing the above error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had installed appium from a different user and the owner of the Appium.app was other user than the user I was trying to run from. Changing the owner to the current user resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by running `ps aux | grep appium` from command line, kill all appium and node processes and then restart appium.