# Appium: A new session could not be created

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

Before posting this question I went to these questions on Stackoverflow and other forums:

1. [A new session could not be created. (Original error: Instruments crashed on startup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248328/a-new-session-could-not-be-created-original-error-instruments-crashed-on-star)
2. [Appium Error : A new session could not be created. (Original error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626529/appium-error-a-new-session-could-not-be-created-original-error-did-not-get)
3. https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/2981

   and did few changes in my code below:

   Code:

   ```
   package test.appium;

   import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;

   import java.io.File;
   import java.net.MalformedURLException;
   import java.net.URL;
   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
   import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
   import org.testng.annotations.Test;

   public class WordPad {
   WebDriver dr;

   @Test
   public void testApp() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
       String apkpath = "D:\\apkdump\\blackcarbon.wordpad.apk";
       File app = new File (apkpath);
       DesiredCapabilities capabilities= new DesiredCapabilities();
       capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"");
       capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","TestOneAdb1");
       capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.2.4.1");
       capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
       capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath());
       capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.wordpad");
       capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.wordpad.Main");
       dr = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);                    
       dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       dr.quit();      
   }   
   }
   ```

   but I am still getting the error:

   > info: [debug] UiAutomator shut down normally
   >
   > error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity
   >
   > info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
   >
   > info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
   >
   > info: [debug] Error: Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity
   >
   > ```
   > at null.<anonymous> (D:\MobileTesting\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:1143:21)
   >
   > at null.<anonymous> (D:\MobileTesting\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:172:9)
   >
   > at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:635:7)
   >
   > at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
   >
   > at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
   >
   > at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
   > ```
   >
   > info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity)","origValue":"Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity"},"sessionId":null}
   >
   > info: [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session [39m[31m500[39m[90m 51290.254 ms - 346[39m [90m[39m
   >   What I tried:
   >
   > 1. Install app manually on emulator and check if its working: It was working
   > 2. Once the app is installed via code:  I can play with manually on emulator, it works perfectly fine.
   > 3. Downgrade `Appium` version from latest `1.1.0` tried but same error
   > 4. Specify `Appium`version capabilities in code, tried but still same error.

Let me know what I am missing, how can I launch app after installation?

Answer (score 0):

Possible Causes:

1.
It seems the issue is with one more missing capability or improper android version:

```
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
```

As you are not using 'Selendroid' as automation mode, so the emulator or device you are using for testing should be of Android 4.2+ .

Please make this sure and mention the above desired capability in the list.

2.
Instead of using

```
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.wordpad.Main");
```

try with

```
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".Main");
```

Comment: I have added `selendroid-standalone-0.12.0-with-dependencies.jar` and wrote one more line with step 2 but it didn't work. So I added Step1 also, alongwith `selendroid-standalone-0.12.0-with-dependencies.jar` and step2. But still same error. Is this code working at your end?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. My error message was also

> "Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make
>   sure it exists and is a launchable activity".

In my case I had different main activity set in two places.

First one - Appium GUI:

```
Appium --> Android Settings --> Main Activity, Package and App Path
```

Second one - in the code:

```
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.company.AppName");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.company.AppName.AppMainActivity");
```

Those two above have to be consistent - the same package and activity.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and it turned out to be because I'd changed my project's directory name, so the path to the apk was wrong. A silly mistake for sure, but probably worth checking just in case.